# Vue Router - How to stop infinite loop in router.beforeEach()

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have this block of code here.

```
Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // AUTH = firebase.auth()
    // it allows me to get the auth 
    // status of the user
    AUTH.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (to.matched.some(m => m.meta.auth) && user) {
            // I am checking if it is the user's first
            // time to login so I can mandatory redirect 
            // them to the setup page.
            isFirstLogin().then(firstLogin => {
                if (firstLogin) {
                    next({ name: 'first-login' }) // this causes infinite loop
                } else {
                    next()
                }
            });
        } else {
            next({ name: 'logout' }); // this causes infinite loop
        }
    })
})
```

However this line `next({ name: 'first-login' })` causes infinite loop.

How do I prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you want `onAuthStateChanged` inside `beforeEach`. That firebase listener only fires on login or logout. The navigation guard will be left hanging because you never call `next`. You should just check if the user is indeed logged in, using `firebase.auth().currentUser`. That would be set by `onAuthStateChanged` somewhere outside `beforeEach`.

Comment: Hello @EricGuan apparently `firebase.auth().currentUser` is resulting to `null` on load of the page coz the `auth()` is not yet initialized after the components were loaded. 

`onAuthStateChanged` actually fires when you use it that way. The fact that it causes infinite loop proves that it is being called. 

Do you have any idea how to solve this? Thanks.